# How to initialize default value to C#7 out variables?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I used `TryParse` to parse a string to number. I need a solution to initialize out variable with default value, So when TryParse fails to convert I get my default value.

Here is the code :

```
long.TryParse(input.Code, out long Code = 123);
//Error CS1525  Invalid expression term '='
```

I want to **strictly** to use C#7 out variables standard.

Comment: What do you mean `initialize with default value`? The value of an out parameter is set by the method. If you want to set a value in case of error, you'll have to write the required code. This *hasn't* changed by the way. That's how out parameters always worked

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry I misunderstood out parameter..

Comment: Let's assume that this made sense from a language standpoint for a second - _"If not why it's not standarded"_ every feature that gets added to the language has to be designed and implemented and adds complexity to the syntax - there simply isn't enough time to do everything, whilst making sure you don't break other things elsewhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whilst the `out` parameter itself cannot take a default value, you can achieve what you want to do with a single expression in C# 7. You simply combine the `out` parameter with a ternary expression:

```
var code = long.TryParse(input.Code, out long result) ? result : 123;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it... The .NET runtime doesn't know anything of "success" or "failure" of `long.TryParse`. It only knows that `TryParse` has a `bool` return value and that after `TryParse` finishes, the `out` variable will be initialized. There is no necessary correlation between `true` and "there is a good value in `result`" and `false` and "there is no good value in `result`".

To make it clear, you could have:

```
static bool NotTryParse(string s, out long result)
{
    return !long.TryParse(s, out result);
}
```

And now? When should your default value be used?

Comment: Yeah.. seems like I misunderstood out variables!

Comment: @MohsenSarkar nothing to feel bad about... *most* people misunderstand "out" variables and the whole by-ref thing. For context, "out" is identical to "ref", just with some compiler tweaks re "definite assignment". And 9 times out of 10: people understand what "ref" means. A point I tried to make here: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/04/spans-and-ref-part-1-ref.html